# MySQL: CHAR (13) or BIGINT(13) when considering performance?

Tags: mysql

I am storing all the possible ISBNS in a table. These isbns are ALWAYS 13 digits long and are ALWAYS numeric. Each ISBN starts with either '978' or '979'. From a purely performance viewpoint, would it be better to have the column as BIGINT (13) or CHAR (13) and why? Is there another way of storing this data which would be more efficient?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513157/mysql-performance-of-unique-varchar-field-vs-unique-bigint

Comment: char 13 takes at least 13 bytes, bigint takes 8 bytes, bigint will be faster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first, `BIGINT(13)` meaning of 13 is not their internal storage space. `BIGINT(n)` always occupies 8 bytes. And, `CHAR(13)` takes 13 bytes. so, BIGINT is faster.

if small size is important to you, while i'm not ISBN expert, if ISBN starts '978' or '979', remain part is 10 digit? then you can create 2 colunms,

`isbn_prefix` CHAR(1), `remain_part` INT. `isbn_prefix` stores '8' for '978', '9' for 979, `remain_part` stores 10 digits. `BIGINT` requires only 4 bytes. so, less than `BIGINT`.

but, Simple is the best. I'll use `BIGINT` if I were you.

Comment: Thank you for the BIGINT Vs. CHAR (13) clarification. However, your suggestion of breaking down the isbn into its prefix and remaining part has raised a doubt: If I were to do that, then when I search for an ISBN (eg: 9780321832184). I would have to do this: SELECT * FROM 'isbns' WHERE prefix = '8' AND remaining_part = '0321832184' . Wouldn't this be slower than: SELECT * FROM isbns WHERE isbn = 9780321832184?

Comment: then, you need to make composite index `INDEX (isbn, prefix)`. or `prefix` has only '8' or '9' isbn INDEX may be enough. do you have a lot of data? then test is easy. but if not, `BIGINT` will be best choice.

Answer (score 4):

I was just doing a test on a 1M row table as part of a similar project that I'm working on.

```
BIGINT -  0.0003 sec
Varchar(13)- 1.3996 sec
CHAR(13) - 1.2910 sec
```

No doubt I'm going with the BIGINT

Answer (score 2):

Most efficient, in terms of storage, would be to use datatype `DECIMAL(13)`.

That would require a total of 6 bytes. (4 bytes will store nine decimal digits, and another 2 bytes are require for the remaining four decimal digits.)

Comment: It would take the MySQL engine more to process the decimal type column than the Bigint which would eventually outweigh the savings of 2 bytes per record..